# Error when run php -S localhost:8080: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. App Engine Standard + MySQL + Getting Started Project

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, localhost, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to run the example app called "**getting-started**" on Google Cloud Platform **App Engine Standard** Environment:

Github source:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/standard/getting-started

Here are my configuration:
app.yaml

```
runtime: php81

env_variables:
    GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET: as1-kendo-picture-storage
    CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: kendo-api-demo:asia-southeast1:bookshelf
    CLOUDSQL_USER: root
    CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: Hello@2023
    CLOUDSQL_DATABASE_NAME: book-data
```

The app worked nicely on production environment when I ran:
`gcloud app deploy`

But **I got the error** when trying to run on localhost from Cloud Shell Editor:
`php -S localhost:8080`

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: PDOException
Code: 2002
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
File: /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/src/app.php
Line: 81
Trace
#0 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/src/app.php(81): PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_sock...', '', '')
#1 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(DI\Container), Object(DI\Definition\FactoryDefinition))
#2 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/php-di/invoker/src/Invoker.php(82): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/FactoryResolver.php(80): Invoker\Invoker->call(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/ResolverDispatcher.php(71): DI\Definition\Resolver\FactoryResolver->resolve(Object(DI\Definition\FactoryDefinition), Array)
#5 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Container.php(390): DI\Definition\Resolver\ResolverDispatcher->resolve(Object(DI\Definition\FactoryDefinition), Array)
#6 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Container.php(139): DI\Container->resolveDefinition(Object(DI\Definition\FactoryDefinition))
#7 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/src/controllers.php(38): DI\Container->get('cloudsql')
#8 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(43): Closure->Google\Cloud\Samples\Bookshelf\{closure}(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Psr7\Response), Array)
#9 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(384): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Psr7\Response), Array)
#10 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\Routing\Route->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#11 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#12 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(341): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#13 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/RouteRunner.php(84): Slim\Routing\Route->run(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#14 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/ErrorMiddleware.php(107): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#15 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(147): Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Routing\RouteRunner))
#16 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#17 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(215): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#18 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(199): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#19 /home/kenluong_com/kendo/getting-started/index.php(38): Slim\App->run()
#20 {main}
```

[Cloud Shell Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgEIx.png)

I guess **there is a problem in the connection** between localhost <=> MySQL.
But I don't know **where and how** to change the configuration.
My purpose to run on localhost is to do **php debugging in realtime**.

Could you please help me to fix this?

I have searched many results about:

> app engine, slim framework, SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.

But cannot solve the problem.

Many thanks,
Ken.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine runs the Cloud SQL Proxy for you and creates a Unix socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`.

To mimic the same connection path locally (or in Cloud Shell), you'll need to run the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy yourself:

```
./cloud-sql-proxy --unix-socket /cloudsql <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#configuring-unix-domain-sockets) for details.